# Good ways to find all solutions of $\cos(2x)=-\sin(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

I'm trying to find good ways ways to find all solutions of $\cos(2x)=-\sin(x)$

I drew out a unit circle and was eventually able to find the solutions. I just looked for values where the $-\sin(x)=\cos(y)$ and then checked to see if $2x = y + 2\pi k$ for some integer $k$.

Is there a more algebraic way to solve this? Or any way better at all? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that $ \cos 2x = 1 - 2 \sin^2x $? If so, do you see a quadratic equation in $ \sin x$?

Comment: I think the approach you described in the question actually is not a bad way to do this.

Comment: @DavidK Eh, I should have totally seen the quadratic as Calvin said and the accepted answer below is pretty great I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT**

Are you aware of the identity
\begin{align*}
\cos(2x) = 1 - 2\sin^{2}(x) 
\end{align*}

You can apply it in order to obtain a quadratic equation.

Another possible approach consists in noticing that
\begin{align*}
-\sin(x) = \sin(-x) = \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + x\right)
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?